# Worksheet_Change function doesn't seem to work

Tags: excel, vba

I am checking this code, but can't make it work.
I just want to fire an event when the worksheet gets a change, any change.
I will limit the change range detection to a couple of columns, but for now I would like to see it just working.
At the moment, nothing happens when I change data on the worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z50")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "CHANGE DETECTED"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In the Immediate Window, type `Application.EnableEvents = True` and hit Enter. Then... how are you "changing data"? Are you dealing with formulas, or manually changing content in the cell?

Comment: Have you tried a debug marker? Have you tried getting rid of the `Intersect` stuff and literally just have a MsgBox in the routine?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.
I tried by changing the cells manually. I added simple numbers in the cells.

This sub is part of a large solution, where I do a lot of stuff like adding "records" (rows) using VBA, exploring them, removing them, etc. So, no, I didn't check if the sub is being called, because it shouldn't be the problem, as the rest of the code is working fine. I mean, all the rest is working, so I can't understand why a simple thing like Worksheet_Change is not being detected.
I am also wondering here if "private" is important for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason that event macros don't work is that they are installed in the wrong place.

Worksheet code is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

*(by the way, your code does work)*

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Mh... yes, I'm pretty noob to VBA, but not SO noob to coding. This chunk of code is just a small part of something much larger I am doing. I need this because I am using VBA to use Excel as a database, I am creating and deleting rows, using them as "records". As I added comments in the input sheet, I need to remove them in the "database", just to not clog the workbook with useless stuff. The rest of the code works perfectly, so I guess that Macros are enabled XD